# Unusual color of text in console

Tags: c++, colors, console

today i need to print colorful text in console, but the color should be "unusual". I've found the only way to colorize text with windowh.h

```
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), colorNumber)
```

Main problem is the limited choice of **colorNumber**, there are only 16 colors, but it is not enough. What if i want to make text color #33F5C8? What if i want to make it transparent? How can i do it?

(nonstandard cpp tools allowed)

Comment: You might try with [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors). Be aware that windows added support for only recently, so you won't get desired result on older versions of windows (e. g. 7 or 8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) you can use the following code to set a RGB based color:

```
\033[38;2;⟨r⟩;⟨g⟩;⟨b⟩m
```

To reset color after change:

```
\033[0m
```

Pay attention that the visual's console might not support it, although the CMD probably does. To check the colors, compile your program and run it using the CMD.